# Accessing serializer fields by url in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## Setup

I have a standard setup with model `Account` and corresponding `AccountSerializer`.

*serializers.py:*

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created')
```

*views.py:*

```
class SingleAccountView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'
    permission_classes = ()
```

*urls.py:*

```
url(r'^account/(?P<id>\w+)$', SingleAccountView.as_view())
```

## Goal

I want to be able to access the properties of my serializer by url, without hardcoding them into `urls.py`. E.g., I want to be able to go to `website.com/account/23/account_name` to get the account name for account 23. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write a view explicitly to do that, as none of the generic views cover that use case.

Something along these lines would be about right...

```
class SingleAccountPropertyView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, id, property_name):
        instance = self.get_object()
        if not hasattr(instance, property_name):
            return Response({'errors': 'no such property'}, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return Response({'property': getattr(instance, property_name)}
```

You could also just use the regular `APIView` instead of `GenericAPIView`, in which case you'd want to write the instance lookup explicitly, instead of using the generic `get_object()`/`lookup_field` functionality that `GenericAPIView` provides.

Comment: Neat, thanks for this explanation and sample code. Would it also be feasible to do this recursively for nested objects?

Comment: Yup, tho again you'd need to deal with that logic yourself.